# How to turn this simple 5 bytes back into 4 bytes ? (algorithm to convert 4 bytes into 5 bytes is known)

Tags: python, algorithm, math

The algorithm to convert input 8 digit hex number into 10 digit are following:

```
Given that the 8 digit number is: '12 34 56 78'

x1 = 1 * 16^8 * 2^3
x2 = 2 * 16^7 * 2^2
x3 = 3 * 16^6 * 2^1
x4 = 4 * 16^4 * 2^4
x5 = 5 * 16^3 * 2^3
x6 = 6 * 16^2 * 2^2
x7 = 7 * 16^1 * 2^1
x8 = 8 * 16^0 * 2^0

Final 10 digit hex is:
=> x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 
=> '08 86 42 98 E8'
```

The problem is - `how to go back to 8 digit hex from a given 10 digit hex (for example: 08 86 42 98 E8 to 12 34 56 78)`

Some sample input and output are following:

```
input                output

11 11 11 11          08 42 10 84 21
22 22 33 33          10 84 21 8C 63
AB CD 12 34          52 D8 D0 88 64
45 78 96 32          21 4E 84 98 62
FF FF FF FF          7B DE F7 BD EF
```

P.S. The problem I think is not limited to 8 or 10 digits. If the input is `11`, the output would be `08`.

Comment: Uh... "8 digit hex", "10 digit hex". Does what you are trying to do have a proper name or a formal description? Because I have to admit that I am completely confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this conversion algorithm:

```
x1 = 1 * 16^8 * 2^3
x2 = 2 * 16^7 * 2^2
x3 = 3 * 16^6 * 2^1
x4 = 4 * 16^4 * 2^4
x5 = 5 * 16^3 * 2^3
x6 = 6 * 16^2 * 2^2
x7 = 7 * 16^1 * 2^1
x8 = 8 * 16^0 * 2^0
```

You can see that after `16^4` it skipped to `16^6`.
Pull one off so that it arranges nicely.

```
x1 = 1 * 16^7 * 16^1 * 2^3
x2 = 2 * 16^6 * 16^1 * 2^2
x3 = 3 * 16^5 * 16^1 * 2^1
x4 = 4 * 16^4 * 2^4
x5 = 5 * 16^3 * 2^3
x6 = 6 * 16^2 * 2^2
x7 = 7 * 16^1 * 2^1
x8 = 8 * 16^0 * 2^0
```

`16^1` is `2^4`, so

```
x1 = 1 * 16^7 * 2^4 * 2^3
x2 = 2 * 16^6 * 2^4 * 2^2
x3 = 3 * 16^5 * 2^4 * 2^1
x4 = 4 * 16^4 * 2^4
x5 = 5 * 16^3 * 2^3
x6 = 6 * 16^2 * 2^2
x7 = 7 * 16^1 * 2^1
x8 = 8 * 16^0 * 2^0
```

Putting them together, you will see that the power goes up nicely.

```
x1 = 1 * 16^7 * 2^7
x2 = 2 * 16^6 * 2^6
x3 = 3 * 16^5 * 2^5
x4 = 4 * 16^4 * 2^4
x5 = 5 * 16^3 * 2^3
x6 = 6 * 16^2 * 2^2
x7 = 7 * 16^1 * 2^1
x8 = 8 * 16^0 * 2^0
```

And multiplying with `2^something` can be seen as a shift left operator.

```
x1 = 1 * 16^7 << 7
x2 = 2 * 16^6 << 6
x3 = 3 * 16^5 << 5
x4 = 4 * 16^4 << 4
x5 = 5 * 16^3 << 3
x6 = 6 * 16^2 << 2
x7 = 7 * 16^1 << 1
x8 = 8 * 16^0 << 0
```

`16^something` is for multiplying with base 16. So that, these 4 bytes of number

```
AAAABBBB CCCCDDDD EEEEFFFF GGGGHHHH
```

Become 5 bytes of this:

```
0AAAA0BB BB0CCCC0 DDDD0EEE E0FFFF0G GGG0HHHH
```

So using that picture, you can create a function that takes the 10 digit hex number and outputs into the 4 digit hex numbers using simple bitwise operations.

For simplicity, I will use unsigned char on this example C code:

```
void convert(unsigned char five[], unsigned char four[]) {
    four[0] = (five[0] << 1) & 0xF0  // 11110000
            | (five[0] << 2) & 0x0C  // 00001100
            | (five[1] >> 6) & 0x03; // 00000011
    four[1] = (five[1] << 3) & 0xF0  // 11110000
            | (five[2] >> 4) & 0x0F; // 00001111
    four[2] = (five[2] << 5) & 0xE0  // 11100000
            | (five[3] >> 3) & 0x10  // 00010000
            | (five[3] >> 2) & 0x0F; // 00001111
    four[3] = (five[3] << 7) & 0x80  // 10000000
            | (five[4] >> 1) & 0x70  // 01110000
            | (five[4])      & 0x0F; // 00001111
}
```

And the output (see the [full code](http://codepad.org/ePg8vcuC)):

```
 08 42 10 84 21      11 11 11 11
 10 84 21 8C 63      22 22 33 33
 52 D8 D0 88 64      AB CD 12 34
 21 4E 84 98 62      45 78 96 32
 7B DE F7 BD EF      FF FF FF FF
```

Comment: @Thai: Thanks a lot for your reply. 

I just checked your code and in the middle of debugging. If the input is: "02 B4 B7 26 87", your code returns "0A AB E9 47". But, according to the algorithm, "0A AB E9 47" should be the output of "02 94 B7 24 87".

Comment: There are unused bits. This means, any of the zeroes in `0AAAA0BB BB0CCCC0 DDDD0EEE E0FFFF0G GGG0HHHH` could be one, and that means that for each eight digit hex numbers, there could be 256 ten digit hex numbers that reverses to the same eight digit numbers.

Comment: This two numbers are one of them: `02 B4 B7 26 87` and `02 94 B7 24 87` both produce the same 4 digits number. It is because the bits that are different in these 2 numbers are not used in the algorithm and could be anything, so they are discarded during reversal.

Comment: @Thai: Thanks for the explanation and your's is the correct answer. So, `0A AB E9 47`'s 5 byte conversion could be both: `02 B4 B7 26 87` and `02 94 B7 24 87` and 254 other variations (in total 2^8=256 as you mentioned).

But, If I am coming from 4 bytes (`0A AB E9 47` in this case) and want to get specific 5 bytes of '02 B4 B7 26 87', can you please spare some hint what would be the operation ? Because according to the 4byte-to-5byte algo. that I posted, `0A AB E9 47` would always produce `02 94 B7 24 87`. Is it possible to get `02 B4 B7 26 87` without changing my algo ?

Comment: The reason I am asking this is because: `02 B4 B7 26 87` can take me back to `0A AB E9 47`. But, `0A AB E9 47` will never drop me back into `02 B4 B7 26 87`. (as it will always produce `02 94 B7 24 87`)

Comment: When converting 5 bytes to 4 bytes, some data are lost, so it won't be possible to convert every values back-and-forth because some data are lost during the operation. [Pidgeonhole](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).